# CSS - Determinate circular progress without animations

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a determinate circular progress without any animation. I am attempting to accomplish without any animations, and by just adjusting the percentage to display the progress.

I've approached this by using purely css. It works great for a bar progress display but I am attempting to adjust the css to make it fit more a look similar to this :

[image]

With 100% displaying a full circle. I've attempted in accomplishing this by adjusting the to `border-radius: 50%` but it does not have the same look what I am attempting to create.

My expected outcome is something similar to the designed I showed above where it is a determinate progress circle without animations and can be adjusted by passing values:

here is an example of my current code:

```
.progress-circle {
    position: relative;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%
}

.determinate-color {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #002F65;
    transition: width .3s linear;
}
```

The progress in this example is determined by adjusting the inline `width` in the html :

```
<div class="progress-circle">
      <div class="determinate-color" style="width: 40%"></div>
  </div>
```

I have provided a jsfiddle of my code, with examples included.

https://jsfiddle.net/vbrhkp78/12/

Comment: I know it's not CSS but here was an intriguing SVG solution to making a looking bit of geometry using SVG: https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/how_to_code_an_SVG_pie_chart maybe you could animate the SVG attributes and get a similar effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something with [Conic Gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/conic-gradient)

[Current Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-conic-gradients)

```js
document.getElementById('r').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const el = document.querySelector('.progress-circle');
  el.style.setProperty('--progress', e.target.value);
})
```

```css
.progress-circle {
  --d: 50px;
  --color: #002F65;
  --progress: 42;
  border-radius: var(--d);
  height: var(--d);
  width: var(--d);
  background: conic-gradient( var(--color) calc(calc(var(--progress) / 100) * 360deg), transparent calc(calc(var(--progress) / 100) * 360deg));
}


/* demo */
body {
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
  place-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-circle"></div>

<input id="r" type="range" value=42>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and this is exactly what I was expecting. Unfortunately, the cross-browser compatibility will be an issue. Is there anything you know of other then using conic-gradient that can be used when approaching this?

Comment: Would you consider using a polyfill? https://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/

Comment: a pollyfill if I understood correctly, will make it compatible across browsers?

Comment: Typically, however that polyfill doesn't appear to support `calc` or css variables inside the `conic-gradient` property, so it probably won't work for you. I think the approach in this article could be a good alternative https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/designing-simple-pie-charts-with-css/. Or go with SVG, or even an image sprite